# No sound Ubuntu 14.04 even after trying posted solutions

Tags: sound, alsa

After upgrading from 12.04 I had no issues at all. After the first reboot/shutdown that is when I experienced problems.

I have tried solutions [here](http://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/) but none of them has worked.

When I ran alsamixer in terminal, this is the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8L1y.jpg).

I did get sound back after using a LiveCD with ubuntu on for a while until I had to boot the system following a kernel update.

Kindly assist to solve this issue.( No sound from speakers or headphones)

Answer (score 0):

In Alsamixer, press F6 and see if you have 2 sound cards , the first one being HDMI : then you can set Pulseaudio to use your second sound card running  pavucontrol (pulseaudio volume control , install if it is not) : in the pavucontrol "output device" tab, activate "set as alternative" , button for the 2nd card (text not sure as i have it in french ) . Restart sounds apps and check.

If no luck, try to run Alsainfo : Copy this command in a terminal and post here the url which will store the result : wget -O alsa-info.sh http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-info.sh && chmod +x ./alsa-info.sh && ./alsa-info.sh

Of course, also upgrade Ubuntu on your pc